# Would extracting hydrogen from the sun lessen its lifespan?

Tags: science-based, space, stars

Relating to my earlier question [Is it a good idea to harvest the sun to terraform Venus?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/236518/is-it-a-good-idea-to-harvest-the-sun-to-terraform-venus)

Suppose that we continue to “mine” the sun for hydrogen to be used as rocket fuel. If we continued to do so, would this begin to deplete the amount of hydrogen in the sun and start to lower it’s life expectancy, eventually causing it to explode/transform into a supergiant?

Answer (score 71):

Assuming you're taking hydrogen from the surface, you'll be lengthening its lifespan.

The sun's outer convective envelope, within which hydrogen is cycled from the surface to its interior, doesn't quite reach its actively-fusing core. That core is supplied entirely by its own internal hydrogen; by the time it's done fusing into helium naturally in ~5 billion years, the outer envelope will still be hydrogen, since it won't have been cycled in.

So the only effect of removing mass from the envelope right now is to reduce the pressure on the core, and with less pressure, the core burns more slowly.

At a certain point, if you deplete the envelope by a significant margin (difficult; we're talking thousands upon thousands of Earth-masses here), you might begin to alter which parts of the Sun are convective. A low-enough mass star is *fully* convective and taking more mass away will simply shrink it until it can't fuse anything more at all.

Comment: See also: [star lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_lifting).

Comment: So it wouldn't shorten the sun's lifespan, but it *would* dim the sun immediately?

Comment: @DanStaley Where do you get "immediately"?

Comment: @DanStaley It'd take many thousands of years for a change in luminosity to fully propagate from the core up to the surface, since photons take so long to escape, but if you're committing to starlifting a serious portion of the Sun then "thousands of years" is the timescale we're talking about. I neglected short-term effects since the question wasn't focused on those, but you might create *more* light for a while by doing major starlifting, because you're pulling glowing plasma off the surface and into space, allowing it more surface area to radiate.

Comment: Stars operate under a "Live Fast, Die Young" principle.

Answer (score 20):

As a rule of thumb, the more massive a star is, the shorter its life is.

If I remember correctly, the more massive a star is, the more densely packed are the atoms in its core and the easier it is for them to fuse, resulting in a quicker burning of the available fuel.

For a reference, you can use [a calculator](https://rechneronline.de/planets/lifespan-star.php) to estimate the life of a star based on its mass:

- A star of 1 solar mass would have a life of 10 billion years
- A star of 0.8 solar masses would have a life of 17.5 billion years

Answer (score 8):

**I doubt it. I seriously doubt it.**

A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away I lived near Coeur d'Alene, Idaho. I remember watching a news broadcast about a lady who was upset because a local golf course had been given permission to draw from Lake Coeur d'Alene to water the course. She was absolutely convinced lake water levels would drop precipitously because of it and demanded that they cease and desist immediately.

- Golf courses require about [152.5 acre-feet of water](https://www.gcsaa.org/uploadedfiles/environment/environmental-profile/water/golf-course-environmental-profile--water-use-and-conservation-report.pdf) annually.
- Lake Couer d'Alene stores about [2,260,000 acre⋅feet of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Coeur_d%27Alene)

Unless you're trying to fuel billions of ships a year, your civilization could realistically draw hydrogen non-stop from its star and, unless you need it to be otherwise in your story, it won't make a measurable dent in the lifespan of the star.

and if you have interstellar travel, this is even less of an issue because you could either (a) mine another star or (b) move to another solar system when your star is mined out.

Comment: "**Even if** you're trying to fuel billions of ships a year". FTFY :) The Sun is big, really big. You'd really need to remove thousands of Earth masses to have any noticeable effect.

Comment: @vsz :-) Are we suggesting that I might have been a bit optimistic about how few ships would be needed to make a dent? I wouldn't be surprised, but I thought "trillions" might leave people wondering that I was being a bozo.

Comment: Acre-feet might be the most american unit of measurement ever. For anyone else wondering: One acre is 4046,86m² and one foot is about 30.5cm meaning one acre-foot is about 1233.5m³

Comment: Agree with the answer, but the analogy is slightly askew for me. If a golf course uses water it does go back to the water table and will re-appear in some body of water somewhere, however the hydrogen will not come back to the star. Its a closed system vs an open system.

Comment: the civilization will *eventually* get to Kardashev 2 and use up the sun to power spaceships, don't worry.

Comment: @user253751 - More like it will use up the sun to power movement of other solar systems to tidier arrangements.

Comment: @SirHawrk, an acre-foot is sufficient water to irrigate one acre of crops with one foot of water.

Comment: @Mark And a cubic meter is sufficient water to irrigate one square meter of crops with one meter of water. Or 10 square meter with Decimeter of water

Comment: I realise this is beside the point of your answer, but the total volume of the lake is not relevant to the concern about the lake's water levels. Imagine a very deep lake with as much volume as you like; if the lake's surface area were 150 acres then removing 150 acre-feet of water from it would lower the water level by 1 foot, regardless of how much water there is in the lake. So it's the lake's surface area that matters, not its volume. Wikipedia says the surface area is about 50 square miles, so the water level would go down by about 10 microns per year (ignoring drainage from the course).

Comment: @Mark That's not the point. The point is, this is an *inter*national site, and only Americans have any idea, how much an acre-feet is. The thoughtful poster uses SI units, only.

Comment: @kaya3 And even that is totally beside the point of the lake story, as lakes typically have inflows and an outflow. The lake's surface only fall by such an amount that the outflow rate shrinks by the average amount of water taken out of the lake.

Comment: @JamesT I wish I could remember who said this, but someone a lot smarter than I once said something along the lines of, "the only way to model and infinitely complex system is with that system, itself." Metaphors and analogies are always weaker than a full scientific explanation. But the issue you bring up is so trivial that it has a statistically zero impact. If we assume the golf course consumed 100% of the water it used to water its lawn and no recycling occurred, the amount used compared to the amount available is *so trivial* that it doesn't matter - which was my point.

Comment: @SirHawrk Yeah, silly Americans. Still using acres and feet as units of measurement. It's a good thing you chimed in when you did because the world can't be trusted to [use Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+acre+feet+to+cubic+meters&client=firefox-b-1-d) and people were going mad with confusion. And it's a very good thing  I didn't use barn-megaparsecs or square-siriometer-litres. Either would have started a zombie apocalypse.

Comment: @kaya3 The only relationship that mattered in my lake analogy was the ratio of the very large volume of the lake to the very low volume of water consumed by the golf course and the demonstration of how ridiculous it is to believe that a civilization could materially affect the lifespan of a star by refueling space ships. If you're worried about anything else, then you're not worried about the original question.

Comment: @JBH who hurt you? Its much easier to have the answer right here instead of having everyone have to Google it

Comment: @SirHawrk Who hurt *you?* Why are you offended by Americans? Don't you realize that most of us (even in the scientific community) when dealing with things outside our field must convert from what's common to you to what's common for us? It might come as a surprise to you, but cubic meters of water means absolutely nothing to me and everyone I know personally. While I and everyone I know personally know exactly what an acre-foot of water means. You're complaining because my answer doesn't meet your desire to not be bothered. If that's the worst thing that happens to you, you're doing great!

Comment: @JBH The only Person who is offended appears to be you. I was making a funny comment and gave a translation for 95% of the world

Comment: @SirHawrk You were making a funny comment? Could have fooled me. That's why I responded with a sarcastic comment - and you still appear to be hurt as you're still leaning on a great many people for a problem you have. (Especially when the only value of the two numbers was the unitless ratio between them.)

Answer (score 4):

I did read somewhere that by controlled removal of matter from the Sun one can make it live ~12 times its predicted lifespan while maintaining constant luminosity.

Of course, this strategy implies removing a great deal more hydrogen than the amount one would need for Venus.

On the other hand, if the goal is to teraform Venus, there are much easier sources of hydrogen available in the Solar system. E.g. the moons of Jupiter and Saturn are almost reachable as a hydrogen source even with today's technology.

Comment: I will just emphasize that this strategy implies removing more hydrogen from the Sun than the total mass of all other bodies within the solar system.  The amount needed for spacecraft propellant and/or terraforming is rather insignificant compared to that.